# Get the primary on-call person details through service now rest api

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

Fairly new to the service now and looking for a way where we could get the primary on call person details for that day from the rest api

Looked through service now documentationwe couldn't find the endpoint details and what parameters it needs

Would greatly appreciate if the community could please point us in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Schedule is in table cmn_schedule. group members is in table cmn_rota_roster.

So you can find the active roster for given time in cmn_schedule and the users and their roles in cmn_rota_roster.